# Problem with href url

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a unordered list like a menu, but when I click on an element of the list, the href is being changed rarely. I set the href like this:

- href="UI/Administracion/Ejemplo.aspx

When I click on any element of the list, the href changes his url like this:

UI/Administracion/Ejemplo/UI/Administracion/Ejemplo.aspx

I'm using ASP 3.5 and the app uses master pages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: suggestion: show some code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your URL to this:

```
href="/UI/Administracion/Ejemplo.aspx"
```

or this:

```
href="Ejemplo.aspx"
```

Comment: Terrific... the first one solution works perfectly! Thank you very much. Greetings to all, i'll see you in my next bug ... =D

Answer (score 1):

instead use this    `href="/UI/Administracion/Ejemplo.aspx`

"/" character maps to your website's root directory

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the href.  Either set it completely as in href="http://www.server.com/UI/Administacion/Ejemplo.aspx", or look into using relative URLs in ASP.NET (via the ~ tilde character and Server.MapPath)